# How do I fix the error message 'The class 'Scene' doesn't have an unnamed constant constructor' in my Flutter code?

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        scrollBehavior: MyCustomScrollBehavior(),
        theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: const Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            //child: Scene(),
      child: Scene(), // Use a named constructor instead
        ),
        ),
    );
    }
}
```

The error message I provided indicates that the class `'Scene'` does not have an unnamed constant constructor. It suggests calling a different constructor instead.

Before:

```dart
child: Scene(),
```

After:

```dart
child: Scene.namedConstructor(), // Use a named constructor instead
```

But this didn't work.

Comment: What is the `Scene` class?  Do you mean [the `Scene` class from `dart:ui`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Scene-class.html)?  But that doesn't make sense because `Scene` is not a `Widget`, which is required for [`SingleChildScrollView`'s `child` argument).